# Need help on CAS authentication with Spring integration

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, cas

I am trying to configure Spring security with CAS authentication.

I have provided following dependency in pom.xml -

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.jasig.cas.client</groupId>
<artifactId>cas-client-core</artifactId>
<version>3.1.11</version>
<scope>runtime</scope>
<type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

I am trying to configure cas client in spring-securaity.xml but I am getting error as

```
The prefix "p" for attribute "p:casServerLoginUrl" associated with an element type "bean" is not bound.
```

Following is spring.security.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">
<bean
name="authenticationFilter"
class="org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter"
p:casServerLoginUrl="https://localhost:8443/cas/login"
p:renew="false"
p:gateway="false"
p:service="https://my.local.service.com/cas-client" />

<bean
name="ticketValidationFilter"
class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas10TicketValidationFilter"
p:service="https://my.local.service.com/cas-client">
<property name="ticketValidator">
<bean class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas10TicketValidator">
<constructor-arg index="0" value="https://localhost:8443/cas" />
</bean>
</property>
</bean>

<bean
name="ticketValidationFilter"
class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Saml11TicketValidationFilter"
p:service="https://my.local.service.com/cas-client">
<property name="ticketValidator">
<bean class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Saml11TicketValidator">
<constructor-arg index="0" value="https://localhost:8443/cas" />
</bean>
</property>
</bean>

<bean
name="ticketValidationFilter"
   class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter"
p:service="https://my.local.service.com/cas-client">
<property name="ticketValidator">
<bean class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator">
<constructor-arg index="0" value="https://localhost:8443/cas" />
</bean>
</property>
</bean>

<bean
name="ticketValidationFilter"   class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter"
p:service="https://my.local.service.com/cas-client"
p:proxyReceptorUrl="/proxy/receptor">
<property name="ticketValidator">
<bean
class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator"
p:proxyCallbackUrl="/proxy/receptor">
<constructor-arg index="0" value="https://localhost:8443/cas" />
</bean>
</property>
</bean>
<bean
name="ticketValidationFilter"
class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilte"    p:service="https://my.local.service.com/cas-client"
p:proxyReceptorUrl="/proxy/receptor">
<property name="ticketValidator">
<bean class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ProxyTicketValidator"
p:acceptAnyProxy="true"
p:proxyCallbackUrl="/proxy/receptor">
<constructor-arg index="0" value="https://localhost:8443/cas" />
</bean>
</property>
</bean>
```

</beans:beans>

I doubt it is having issue with namespace. Can anybody help me correcting the namespace or if i need to change anything in this?

Can anybody refer some online CAS integration with spring security material so that I can check and implement the same.

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it as per follow:

```
<bean
name="authenticationFilter"
class="org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter">
<property name="casServerLoginUrl" value="https://localhost:8443/cas/login"></property>
<property name="renew" value="false"></property>
<property name="gateway" value="false"></property>
<property name="service" value="https://my.local.service.com/cas-client"></property>
</bean>
```